# Can I programatically open a new query window?

Tags: ms-access, vba

**I'm trying to figure out if/how I can generate a new query window in the Design View either via a macro or VBA code.**

Specifically, I want to open a new, blank query in SQL View so I can quickly test SQL code. This is a common activity for me.

I usually create a new query manually via the Ribbon: *Create tab > Query Design button > Close (Show Table window) button > SQL View button.* This results in a new window called Query1 (or Query2, etc.).

I'd like to condense all of those multiple clicks into a keyboard shortcut or a single macro button on the Quick Access Toolbar. Note that I'm using Access 2010.

**Possible?**

Comment: BTW, I saw that I should not use the regular "macros" tag for a question that relates to Access macros, a.k.a., *UI macros.* Is there an alternative tag that I should use?

Comment: I edited my question to clarify that I'm using Access 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to a module:

```
Function NewQueryInSqlView()

    ' Send the ESC key, without waiting for processing,
    ' to cancel the select table dialog that occurs when designing new query
    SendKeys "{ESC}", False

    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdNewObjectDesignQuery ' create new query
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSQLView ' switch to SQL view

End Function
```

To execute the code by way of a keyboard shortcut, create a new macro, and ensure "Macro Names" column is visible.
Add the following row to macro with the following values in the specified columns:

```
Macro Name: +{F3}
    Action: RunCode
            with Function Name argument: NewQueryInSqlView()
```

Save this macro as "AutoKeys". This macro will map <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> to the execution of `NewQueryInSqlView()`. Note that choosing a key mapping starting with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> (the `^` character) will be problematic due to the `SendKeys` statement in `NewQueryInSqlView()`.

Comment: The VBA code is just what I wanted. Bravo. However, I'm using Access 2010, so I cannot "ensure 'Macro Names' column is visible" as suggested. (The macro builder 'grid' was replaced by the Macro Designer in 2010.) Alternatively, I was able to create an AutoKeys macro with a Submacro action named *+{F3}.*

Comment: @EJMak your [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10774250) is probably substantial enough to be its own answer. If this answer helped you arrive [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10774250) you can always reference this in your answer. Unfortunately I have to reject the edit as it differs substantially from the author's intent

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Editing is new to me, but I'm not sure how my suggested edits deviate from the author's intent/goal, and how it does so "substantially." Yes, I expanded on what was written, but I focused on clarifying. Do the rules disallow/discourage changes to style (using an outline format) and/or adding details (expanding to cover a current version of the software)? I also don't think I could use my changes as my "own" separate answer, without plagiarizing. @AnAccess2007Guy really wrote the fundamental parts, not me. Any suggestions for paring down my edit would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function and call it from a macro:

```
Public Function foo()
    Dim qdf As QueryDef    
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("qNew", "SELECT 'd' as foo")
    DoCmd.OpenQuery qdf.Name
End Function
```

This will create the query and open it

The macro is a RunCode command that runs the above function.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer my question. I want to replace the clicks described in my question. Your VBA creates & saves a new query object -- with a single column -- and then opens it in the datasheet view.

Comment: You can add the macro to your ribbon. You can't create an empty query and save it so I had to  put some SQL in the CreateQueryDef . You can also change the view in which the query opens to design view: DoCmd.OpenQuery qdf.Name, acViewDesign

Answer (score 0):

Try This code:

```
Sub EmptyQuery()

  Dim Qname As String
  Qname = "mQname"

  On Error Resume Next
   CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef Qname
  On Error GoTo 0

  DoCmd.OpenQuery Qname, acViewDesign    

End Sub
```